# Rename attachment of InfoPath through Event Receiver for Office365

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, event-receivers, attachments

I am having a `Document Library` named `TestForm` in my Office365 site.I have created InfoPath Form for that library that contains `FileAttachment` control.

Now my requirement is to rename the attachment of InfoPath through `EventReceiver`.

Can anyone have gone through such requirement or any idea about this?.

Please let me know your views.

Thanks